# Using props, how to get the array values inside of .js file in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
export const fruitsdata = [
  {
    id: "1",
    fruit: "freshapples",
    value: "3"
  },

  {
    id: "2",
    fruit: "Notfreshapples",
    value: "1"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    fruit: "freshmangoes",
    value: "3"
  },

  {
    id: "4",
    fruit: "Notfreshmangoes",
    value: "1"
  }
];
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="fruit in fruits" :key="fruit.id">
      freshapples: {{ fruit.value }} Notfreshapples{{ fruit.value }}

      freshmangoes:{{ fruit.value }} Notfreshmangoes:{{ fruit.value }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import fruitsdata from "../fruitsdata";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      data: fruitsdata,
    };
  },
  props: {
    fruitsdata: {
      required: true,
      type: Object,
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I am trying to get data from "fruitsdata.js" file and bind the data in the html. But not sure, what's wrong. unable to use the get the data from .js file??

Error i am getting now is:-

[Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "fruitsdata"

[Vue warn]: Property or method "fruits" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

code:- https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-boyd-m3ib6?file=/src/fruitsdata.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there's a couple of things wrong with your code.

First of all, you do not need to use props if you are loading the data from a file. Also the props are used to pass data to the component (e.g. `<hello-world :fruits="fruitsdata">`.

Next problem is with your import statement. Because you are exporting a const you need to wrap `fruitsdata` in curly braces to import that variable correctly.

I've edited your code and it should work (not tested).

```js
export const fruitsdata = [
  {
    id: "1",
    fruit: "freshapples",
    value: "3"
  },

  {
    id: "2",
    fruit: "Notfreshapples",
    value: "1"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    fruit: "freshmangoes",
    value: "3"
  },

  {
    id: "4",
    fruit: "Notfreshmangoes",
    value: "1"
  }
];
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="fruit in fruits" :key="fruit.id">
        {{ fruit.fruit }}: {{ fruit.value }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { fruitsdata } from "../fruitsdata";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      fruits: fruitsdata,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: But i am getting wrong data multiple times for each array value. like in freshapple i have "3". and notfreshapple like "1". But it is printing like freshapples: 3 Notfreshapples3 freshmangoes:3 Notfreshmangoes:3
freshapples: 1 Notfreshapples1 freshmangoes:1 Notfreshmangoes:1
freshapples: 3 Notfreshapples3 freshmangoes:3 Notfreshmangoes:3
freshapples: 1 Notfreshapples1 freshmangoes:1 Notfreshmangoes:1

Comment: you have it in for loop  so you display these 4 field for every fruit ,  make only one field to display name and value

Comment: Since this because you are jus looping through the array you have defined, there is no logic defined to check whether it is freshapples or notfreshapples. If you want to do this let me know i will update the code accordingly

Comment: Yes sample output like:-  apples: (freshapple-value)---(not freshapple--value)
mangoes: (freshmango-value)---(not freshmangoes--value)

Answer (score 0):

Here you are importing data from a javascript file passing the props remove the props and use the data value like below and Also destruct fruits data since you have used default keyword while you exported the fruitsdata

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="fruit in fruits" :key="fruit.id">
      <p v-if="fruit.fruit==="freshapples">freshapples: {{ fruit.value }}</p>
      <p v-if="fruit.fruit ==="Notfreshapples">Notfreshapples: {{ fruit.value }}</p>
      <p v-if="fruit.fruit ==="freshmangoes">freshmangoes: {{ fruit.value }}</p>
      <p v-if="fruit.fruit ==="Notfreshmangoes">Notfreshmangoes: {{ fruit.value }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {fruitsdata} from "../fruitsdata";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      fruits: fruitsdata,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
h3 {
  margin: 40px 0 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
a {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Not getting the accurate value in each value like "freshapple"....... arrays. and its getting the duplicate values for each array val

Comment: @markerj i have updated the code for you for what you requiring

Answer (score 0):

You don't need props, you aren't define any in parent component. In this case you should put fruitsdata import in curly braces, also your fruits variable doesn't exist it is called data, rename data to fruits

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="fruit in fruits" :key="fruit.id">
      freshapples: {{ fruit.value }} Notfreshapples{{ fruit.value }}

      freshmangoes:{{ fruit.value }} Notfreshmangoes:{{ fruit.value }}
    </div>
    <div v-for="fruit in fruits" :key="fruit.id">
      {{ fruit.fruit }}: {{ fruit.value }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { fruitsdata } from "../fruitsdata";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      fruits: fruitsdata,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-boyd-m3ib6?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-brook-wnrhh

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <span v-for="apple in apples" :key="apple.id">
        {{ apple.fruit }}: {{ apple.value }}
      </span>
    </div>
    <span v-for="mango in mangoes" :key="mango.id">
      {{ mango.fruit }}: {{ mango.value }}
    </span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { fruitsdata } from "../fruitsdata";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      fruits: fruitsdata,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    apples() {
      return this.fruits.filter((fruit) => {
        return (
          fruit.fruit === "freshapples" || fruit.fruit === "Notfreshapples"
        );
      });
    },
    mangoes() {
      return this.fruits.filter((fruit) => {
        return (
          fruit.fruit === "freshmangoes" || fruit.fruit === "Notfreshmangoes"
        );
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

use of computed properties to display them inline
https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-brook-wnrhh?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: Not getting the accurate value in each value like "freshapple"....... arrays. and its getting the duplicate values for each array val

Comment: you have it in for loop so you display these 4 field for every fruit , make only one field to display name and value, example in second codecsandbox

Comment: I mean like,....sample output like:- apples: (freshapple-value)---(not freshapple--value) mangoes: (freshmango-value)---(not freshmangoes--value)

Comment: I've edited the answer to output in the format `notFreshApples: [value]`.  If you actually need to output it per fruit and then the fresh and notfresh count you would have to edit your object.

Comment: Thanks for editing the sandbox. Can i get output like this....apples: (fruit. value)---( fruit.-value) mangoes: (fruit.value)---(fruit--value)  for this output, do i need to point to array position value???

Answer (score 0):

just change

```
import fruitsdata from "../fruitsdata"
```

to

```
import { fruitsdata } from "../fruitsdata";
```

and

```
data() {
 return {
   data: fruitsdata,
 };
}
```

to

```
data() {
 return {
   fruits: fruitsdata,
 };
}
```